# twitter bootstrap typeahead change dropdown menu width based on query

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not really sure if this is jQuery-related, but I have a strong suspicion. My issue is detailed in this picture:

[image: problem picture using typeahead, field in autocomplete too long for width]

The query result is longer than the width and it doesn't scale/resize. I tried to change bootstrap-typeahead.js with

```
  _resizeMenu : function() {
        var ul = this.$menu;
        ul.css("min-width", this.$element.outerWidth());
    }
```

but no go... 
I would like to keep the size of the search box, but I don't want to change the font as it would make everything else too small. I want the dropdown box to extend according to size of query. I am using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 by the way. Has anyone else solved this problem?

Comment: you should be able to do this with pure css, (eg no JS at all)

Comment: this is more of a CSS issue, it's weird because the typeahead demo in the boostrap docs is working correctly for me even when I make the items really long, can you post a link to your site?

Comment: not if you want to do it dynamically based on query result though...

Comment: i think it has to do with .dropdown-menu width being 160px, which is ok, but not for typeahead

Comment: @koala_dev which typeahead demo are you talking about? i can't find a demo that does it right

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I figured out the error. It is something that doesn't seem to agree in bootstrap.css

```
 .pull-right > .dropdown-menu {
  //right: 0;
  left: auto;
  }
```

have to delete `right: 0`. this of course only works if you're using pull-right like i am for navbar search.